# using with Xcode the GPS, the Accelerometer and the Compass ?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

How can I use Phonegap in the same program with Xcode to be able to use the GPS, the Accelerometer and the Compass all together ?

Answer (score 0):

I did found a good example from an ebook on the Web. Google it you can find it.

The book is named : Pro iOS 5 augmented reality [ressource électronique]
Roche, Kyle. [New York] : Apress ; New York : Distributed to the book trade by Springer, c2011.

The example covers GPS, Accelerometer and Compas. The trick he uses so the user can see the data is through a tabbed interface. Chapter 4 covers the sensors. The source is here : github.com/kyleroche/Professional_iOS_AugmentedReality.

The question that I have, is how can I use simutaneously all those sensors which are defined in their separate interfaces ?

My goal is to record the data into a mySQL database at specific time lapses, or by a push of a button.

Thanks

Regis